# Export managed C# function to return changed char* parameter to unmanaged code

Tags: c#, c++, .net, pinvoke, dllexport

I have a native C++ (I think) app which can be configured to load a certain dll and call a function. This function returns int, takes in four parameters, should change at least one of the two and return a value.
According to the manual this function should be defined in C++ as:

```
__declspec( dllexport ) int funcName(const char* par1, const char* par2, char* par3, char* par4);
```

However, by demand, this function should be implemented in C#. I am using Unmanaged Exports to allow me to use:

```
[DllExport("funcName", CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static unsafe int funcName(string par1, string par2, string par3, string par4) {
    // sample for par3 only when using StringBuilder instead of string
    // but is similar with other types
    par3 = new StringBuilder(256); 
    par3.Append("12345"); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Parameters 1 and 2 work just fine (I can messagebox the values received), however I have tried (at least) the following as the 3rd and 4th parameters:

```
char* =>
=> string
=> StringBuilder
=> char[]
```

all of these with `[In], [Out], [In,Out], out, ref`.

Function should change the value of par3 and par4 and return an integer back to the calling application.
The application reads the value of par3 (it is actually an integer represented as string) and writes it out to the log file. After examining the log file, the value is not the one set in funcName(...).

Most commonly the value is "" (empty), however only when using `char[]` with `out` or `ref` there seems to be a value passed back, but it is just a few weird chars (not the value that is set in funcName).

**So the question would be, how to return char* parameter when calling a managed dll function from unmanaged code?**

Comment: Are par3 and par4 char pointers to strings or are they receiving addresses for a single characters?

Comment: Don't you need to set the character set otherwise they'll become `wchar_t *`?

Comment: @ta.speot.is No. The default is ANSI.

Comment: I wrote all the information I had above. The solution that worked is marked below.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm trying to find a reference for the default. According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h(v=vs.110).aspx#cpcondefaultmarshalingforstringsanchor5) the default is `UnmanagedType.LPTStr (default)` which is *A pointer to a null-terminated array of platform-dependent characters.* At the start of the article: *...characters within the string can be marshaled as Unicode or ANSI, or in a platform-dependent manner (Unicode on Microsoft Windows NT, Windows 2000, and Windows XP; ANSI on Windows 98 and Windows Millennium Edition (Windows Me).*

Comment: @ta.speot.is On CE the default is Unicode because that's all there is there. Everywhere else the default is `Ansi`. Of course, what matters here is what `UnmanagedExports` does. Because this is not `DllImport`. But I'm quite sure that Robert followed the precedent of `DllImport`.

Comment: @ta.speot.is FWIW, the reference you are looking for, for `DllImport` is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.charset.aspx

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Right, when using `DllImportAttribute` it has its own behaviour vs. marshalling an arbitrary `string` on its own in an interface/struct/class. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I doubt very much that `UnmanagedImports` will do the work for you. It won't magic a `StringBuilder` into existence unless I am very much mistaken. I think you need to code it like this:

```
[DllExport("funcName", CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static int funcName(string par1, string par2, IntPtr par3, IntPtr par4) 
{
    string inputStr = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(par3);
    string outputStr = "foo\0";
    byte[] outputBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(outputStr);
    Marshal.Copy(outputBytes, 0, par3, outputBytes.Length);
    return 0; 
}
```

Note that I have removed the `unsafe` since that is not needed.

Comment: I'm sorry for completely mis-understanding your question. I hope I've done better this time round.

Comment: THANK YOU! I've been looking at so many different similar questions for this answer for almost a week now. I wish I had a greater reputation at the moment so I could upvote this solution, because it's the first one that works. Thank you again!